# Which Select statement is faster 1)cluster 2)nonClustered 3)with no indexes

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlperformance

In sybase 12.5 
there are 3 tables with respective indexes

- employee_1 table with clustered index on id column
- employee_2 table with Non-clustered index on id column
- employee_3 table with No index on id column

Which select will be faster and why ?

```
select * from employee_1 
select * from employee_2 
select * from employee_3
```

I think 3rd select should be faster as its not using any keys and compiler scan entire page to retrieve than using index page, please let me know. thanks

Comment: I would think they would all perform the same given same data in each table.  Why: the indexes can't be used so all 3 would use a Full Table Scan, as there's no limits imposed upon the data.

Comment: I think that the indexes are irrelevant here.

Comment: what if i changed selects to get max(id) in all three

Comment: Please: Ask 1 question per post. Use comments to request clarification, not ask new quesitons. Please don't ask us to do your homework for you. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

While you are not limiting your query based on id , there is no difference.
but if you want to look up ids and you have a huge amount of records , then clustered indexing would help